# req.user data not displayed in the view

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have an express server with passport-local stategy, passport-local and passport-local-mongoose also installed.I want to access current user model as json to read and write data into it. My headache is that object doesn't want to display the data inside my view. It's loading with no errors and I cannot understand what's happening. Please help me!

Here is my express config:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
morgan = require('morgan'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
expressSession = require('express-session'),
hash = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
path = require('path'),
passport = require('passport'),
localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
port = process.env.PORT || 8080,
User = require('./app/models/user'),
routes = require('./app/routes/api');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dashboard');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
secret: 'keyboard kat',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'X-Requested-With, content-          type, Authorization');
next();
});

app.use('/user', routes);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/views', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('not found :(');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.end(JSON.stringify({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
}));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

And the route which I use to pull the data:

```
router.get('/data', function (req, res) {
res.send(req.user);
});
```

Сhrome dev tools returns correct object:

[Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKPNi.jpg)

Angular service:

```
angular.module('main')
.factory('MenuService', function ($http) {

    function getData() {
        $http.get('/user/data')
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
    }

    return {
        info: getData
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('main')
.controller('menuController', function ($mdSidenav, MenuService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.toggleMenu = function () {
        $mdSidenav('menu').toggle();
    };

    vm.info = MenuService.info();

});
```

And finaly the view:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" ng-controller="menuController as menu">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()" aria-label="open menu">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="../../assets/img/hmg.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <span flex></span>
    <h1>{{menu.info.name}}</h1>
</div>
</md-toolbar>
```

And nothing happens :( No view, no errors, absolutely nothing:

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy6gj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a **promise**
 when dealing with async calls or use **pub-sub pattern** for telling that your data arrived.

What is happening is that the  `getData`  function gets called, in the background fetches the data, but it is not returned to the the caller of the `getData` caller. Why? Because inside `getData` nothing is returned. Something needs to be returned.

Here is a solution returning the promise.

**Update** : Sorry, sometimes I forgot that `$http` returns a resp object, which has the data. Updated the code according to that.
So in your service :

```
angular.module('main')
.factory('MenuService', function ($http) {

    function getData() {
        return $http.get('/user/data'); //no preprocessing just returning the result of the http call
    }

    return {
        info: getData
    }
});
```

And in your controller

```
angular.module('main')
.controller('menuController', function ($mdSidenav, MenuService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.toggleMenu = function () {
        $mdSidenav('menu').toggle();
    };
    //todo this will be called whenever menuController gets initiated
    //better to put into user action or run only one time...
    MenuService.info().then(function(resp){
       console.log(resp); //here is the response
       vm.info = resp.data;
    }, function(err){
       //todo when no data arrived
    });

    return vm;
});
```

Also `.success` and `.error` are deprecated according to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @eenagy! I made as you wrote, but still nothing happens :(

Comment: here:[Postman](http://i.imgur.com/sqhgtHj.jpg?1) and [Browser](http://i.imgur.com/LwZZ11B.jpg?1)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to write 'vm.info = resp.data' insted of 'vm.info = data' :) You just saved my head from blowing :)

Answer (score 0):

you can write this statement in async call.

```
return vm;
```

your `vm` is nothing but `this` object.You dont need to return it from controller.

Your `controller as` syntax is automatically bind `this` object to scope object.

Please remove it.

Let the remain statement as it is.

```
MenuService.info().then(function(resp){
       console.log(resp); //here is the response
       vm.info = resp.data;
    }, function(err){
       //todo when no data arrived
    });
```